# Svg loaded into img tag is blank

Tags: javascript, image, svg

I've been struggling with this for hours.  I extracted svg from the html and uploaded as a file.  I then updated an img tag with the url to the new file.  But it's blank.  If I open the url directly in browser, its perfect, but in the img tag, its blank.

Here's the image in question:
https://sulfur-funmobility.netdna-ssl.com/media/permImageUploads/26730/4/6/6/9/MEEwMTA1MjQxZjlhXzE0Njg1NDM3MzY3NzhfMTNfMg.svg

here it is loaded int the image:
http://codepen.io/rgallison/pen/AXxrjW

```
<img src="https://sulfur-funmobility.netdna-ssl.com/media/permImageUploads/26730/4/6/6/9/MEEwMTA1MjQxZjlhXzE0Njg1NDM3MzY3NzhfMTNfMg.svg"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While luminome's solution was a good one that worked, it wasn't responsive.  However, because of their help, I was able to figure it out.

First, the image wasn't showing up because it was too large.  I had a transform attribute on my svg, so I took that off.

Now the svg showed up, but not positioned correctly or responsive.

Second, I needed to add a viewBox to the svg to make it responsive.

Together, I have the solution I need.

Thanks luminome!

Answer (score 1):

Exciting! I was just working with some SVG today and suggest looking into using an OBJECT tag for your SVG because it might offer more flexibility.

That said. It's showing up blank because it's too big. To get control, use the SVG as a background image for your `<img>` tag. Paste the following into your codepen css window:

```css
img {
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-image: url('https://sulfur-funmobility.netdna-ssl.com/media/permImageUploads/26730/4/6/6/9/MEEwMTA1MjQxZjlhXzE0Njg1NDM3MzY3NzhfMTNfMg.svg');
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: -800px -400px; 
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 2000px 2000px;

}
```

```html
<img src="" width="300" height="150"/>
```

It took some guessing about the original size. I hope this helps!

Comment: I tried using object to no avail. But I will try this and report back.  Completely forgot about this method

Comment: Ok, it shows up now.  I just need to figure out how to scale down

Comment: This is fantastic. Thank you! The only problem is that its not responsive